# File Access is Denied blah.dbf

Tags: visual-foxpro

1. I opened the DBC file
2. Entered a query into the command window

[image: vfp screenshot of the error]

> File access is denied \some-server\our db\sometable.dbf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to issue `USE ____ SHARED IN 0`

```
OPEN DATABASE "\\some-server\our db\blah.dbc" SHARED
USE sometable SHARED IN 0
SELECT * FROM sometable
```

I stumbled across this when I opened the Modify dialog via a right click on the table and then my query was able to run.  I then pull the above command from the command window.

Comment: Or, alternatively, execute SET EXCLUSIVE OFF before executing the other commands, without the SHARED clauses.